# Infinite scroll for text in post with url page change

Tags: plugins, pagination

I've been looking for a solution to my problem for quite some time.

I would divide the text of an article, in parts by adding the **"paging"** infinite scroll and so far I have seen that it is possible with this component:
http://demo.pagelinksplus.com/

I would also, in addition, loading the text "infinity", at every load, also changes the url of the page as it happens with paging plugin `Articles`

- www.webisite.com/articolo
- www.webisite.com/articolo/1
- www.webisite.com/articolo/2
- www.webisite.com/articolo/4

Page 1 - 2 - 3 - ...

I'm referring to the infinite scroll only on a single text article.

Can you give any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify (or create your own) the script that does the loading to change the URL  once he loads a new page. Changing the URL may not be so simple, but you can have a look at this question for tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page